# Mac, safari, background-position:fixed and iframe?

Tags: macos, iframe, safari, background

please help us with the problem in markup for http://mamma-mia.me.
Bug  appears only in the safari browser on Macintosh.
The main problem with the background-position:fixed and iframe (vimeo player) which lay over the background. In this case background are disappear.
position:fixed are need for paralaxe effect and we can't change this property.

Comment: See also: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25216

Did you find a work-around, other than not doing the overlap?

Comment: I worked around this by detecting Mac/Safari and outputting decreased functionality for the people using that system. Kind of like dealing with IE6, ha ha ha.