# Embedding videos from Vimeo is messing up CSS position:fixed <div>s on my page

Tags: css, vimeo

The position:fixed s works perfectly fine when I do not embed a video from Vimeo. Any one knows why and how to work around it? It never used to be like that, only recently.

Comment: Can you provide example code of the section where the problem arises? Also, what do you mean by "messing up"?

Answer (score 0):

Does this question's discussion solve your problem? [Mac, safari, background-position:fixed and iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821568/mac-safari-background-positionfixed-and-iframe)

Original poster stated: "I worked around this by detecting Mac/Safari and outputting decreased functionality for the people using that system."

I would recommend implementing separate CSS for whichever browsers are causing the issue. Can you provide more details about the problem?